# Вывод части записей и довывод остальных при прокрутке

Tags: mysql, ajax, php, javascript

Вывод определенного количества записей, а при прокрутке страницы вниз - вывод остальных. На примере аудиозаписей, друзей, новостей и прочего в контакте. Как такое же можно сделать?

Я вывел из базы допустим 20 записей, а чтобы при прокрутке вниз выводились по очереди остальные.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Реализация довольно проста,

1. Отлавливаете событие `onscroll` у окна
2. Проверяете, находиться ли пользователь внизу страницы
3. Если да, то загружаете посредством ajax доп. контент

С jquery получиться что-то вроде:

```
var page = 1; //Счетчик загруженых данных
$(window).scroll(function() 
{
     if  ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) 
     {
          //Пользователь внизу страницы, подгружаем контент
          page++; 
          $.ajax({
              type: "GET",
              cache: false,
              url: '[ПУТЬ]?page=' + page,
              success: function(data) {
                   $('#container').append(data);
              }
          }
      }
});
```

Comment: Спасибо, попробую.