# Определить, что юзер долистал до низа страницы

Tags: jquery, javascript

Всем доброго дня, столкнулся с такой мелочью: как определить на js/jquery, что юзер долистал до низа страницы? Что-то ничего в голову не приходит... Хотел определять используя $(window).offset(), но этот метод не применим к этому объекту...
Знатоки, подскажи! Заранее спасибо :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ваш вопрос связан с [этим](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/23283/%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B5). Попробуйте так:

```
$(window).scroll(function() 
{
     if  ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) 
     {
          //Пользователь долистал до низа страницы
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

А если через `$(document.body).offset() и $(window).height()`?

Примерно так:

```
if($(document.body).offset().top + $(window).height() == $(document.body).height()){
    //blablabla, только не так грубо - я показал лишь принцип
}
```

Comment: `$(document.body).offset().top;` всегда возвращает 0.  

    $(window).height();
    $(document.body).height();  

Всегда константны.  
  
Т.е. ищем другое решение...

Comment: Тьфу ты, точно). offset() возвращает координаты левого верхнего угла. Надо через $(document.body).scrollTop.    

>всегда константны  
А если изменить размеры окна?

Answer (score 0):

Для того, чтобы определить на сколько пикселей прокручен документ, нужно обратиться к свойствам scrollTop и scrollLeft объекта document.documentElement, если браузер в режиме следования стандартам, или document.body, если браузер в режиме "quirks mode".

```
var html = document.documentElement;
alert("Вы уже прокрутили "+ html.scrollTop +"px этой страницы");
```

Определяешь высоту Body и смотришь если html.scrollTop равен ей.

Answer (score 0):

```
let heightTop = 0;
const idClearScroll1 = setInterval(function () {
  window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
  let height = document.body.scrollHeight;
console.log(height)
 
  if (heightTop !== height) {
    heightTop = height;
  } else {
   clearInterval(idClearScroll1);
  }
}, 2000);
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: setInterval() для этого точно не нужен... Ответ есть тут
https://translated.turbopages.org/proxy_u/en-ru.ru.6ace5f93-63a5ce9e-8f769a32-74722d776562/https/stackoverflow.com/questions/3962558/javascript-detect-scroll-end